# How to refresh translations in i18next React?

Tags: reactjs, localization

I am loading tranlations from url based on user logged in information. I sent back userId for translations so how to load translations after user logIn.

Comment: Have you tried to call changeLanguage? https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react/src/App.js#L40

Comment: Like my default Language is English , if I change to any language(Russian) First Time changeLanguage load translations.but after that it load translations from cache  .

Comment: would be nice to see an example